# Building custom split view using container views

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to build a custom split view controller for iPad using 2 container views that embed UINavigationControllers... 
I managed to do all that but I am having problems with setting up constraints so that everything resizes nicely.

This is what I have so far:
[image]

I wont to be able to resize master view (left container) in a way that detail view (right container) resizes itself also to consume the space that master view left while resizing it self. So I would like to end up like this:

[image]

among other tries I tried adding these constraints:

master container: top to parent, left  to parent, bottom to tabbar, height, placeholder width
detail container: top to parent, left  to master container, bottom to tabbar, right to parent, height, placeholder width

When I resize master container from code, the detail controller always stays at its original place.

I tried 100 scenarios and nothing worked yet.

I am doing something fundamentally wrong with auto layout but just cant figure out what..

This is the resize code:

```
    -(void)ShowMaster:(BOOL)bShow animated:(BOOL)bAnimated
    {
        CGRect frame = masterViewContainer.frame;

        if(bShow){
            frame.size.width = 280;
        }
        else{
            frame.size.width = 50;
        }

        masterViewContainer.frame = frame;

    }
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
OK, I made some progress, replaced my resize code with this one:

```
-(void)ShowMaster:(BOOL)bShow animated:(BOOL)bAnimated
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    if(bShow){
        [masterViewContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:masterViewContainer
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:masterViewContainer
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:0.5
                                                               constant:280]];


    }
    else{
        [masterViewContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:masterViewContainer
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:masterViewContainer
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:0.5
                                                               constant:50]];

    }
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now detail resizes, but when I try to expand master, nothing happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. In my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(masterWidthConstraint == nil){
        masterWidthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:masterViewContainer
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:masterViewContainer
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            multiplier:0.0
                                                              constant:280];


        [masterViewContainer addConstraint:masterWidthConstraint];
    }


}
```

In my ShowMaster method i just update that constraint and animate like this:

```
-(void)ShowMaster:(BOOL)bShow animated:(BOOL)bAnimated
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];

    if(bShow){
        masterWidthConstraint.constant = 280;
    }
    else{
        masterWidthConstraint.constant = 50;
    }

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

And in my IB i set placeholder constraint form master view width... And it works. Only thing that I couldn't do is make a IBOutlet to IB width constraint, and couldn't figure out why, but it works like this just fine so...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   //your code

}
```